# Calendar Web Application Layout Troubleshoot

Tags: html, css

Currently working on the calendar portion of a project and while this is what I am doing as I learn HTML and CSS (+JavaScript) I am a bit stuck on a few points.

So far I've been able to get the layout using flex only but I am not sure if I am approaching the problem the right way. I've been researching and maybe a grid will solve my problem although I am confused as to how to keep what I have so far and perhaps insert the grid in between the days of week and time segments.

My code both in HTML and CSS is displayed below:

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
  
  body {
      background-color: rgb(191, 207, 207);

  }

  .nav-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #navbar {
      background-color: #0f2635;
      display: flex;
      color: tomato;
      justify-content: center;
      list-style: none;
      padding: 15px;
      align-items: center;
      width: 95%;
      border: 2px solid #0f2635;
      border-radius: 15px;
      position: fixed;
      overflow: hidden;
      z-index: 1;
      
      
  }

  #navbar li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: rgb(48, 192, 132);
      padding-left: 150px;
      flex: 1;
      font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
      font-size: 20px;
      white-space: nowrap;
  }


  .rightmost {
      flex: initial;
  }

  #hours {
      display: flex;
      width: 5%;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-left: 1px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      flex-direction: column;
      white-space: nowrap;
      
    }

  #hours li {
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(255, 150, 51);
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 150, 51);
    border-radius: 8px ;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 2px 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 50px 5px 50px 5px;
    font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(0, 19, 192);
    z-index: -1;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }

    #hours li:first-of-type {
        margin-top: 200px;
    }
    
    #days {
     padding-left: 80px;
   
       
        width: 0 auto;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        flex: 1;
        position: fixed;
        
    }

    #days li {
       
        display: flex;
        list-style: none;
        background-color: teal;
        border: 2px solid teal;
        border-radius: 8px;
        padding: 2rem 3.6vw 2rem 3.5vw;
        margin: 105px 8px 0px 8px;

        
       

    }

    .hide {
        position: fixed;
        background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(191,207,207,1) 88%, rgba(191,207,207,1) 97%, rgba(191,207,207,0.1) 100%);
        padding: 103px;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        display: flex;
        z-index: 0;
        
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Agenda Eternite: Triunfo</title>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
      <header>
          <nav class="nav-container">
            
            <ul id="navbar">
                  
                  <li><a href="">Ejercito</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Torres</a></li>
                  <li> <a href="Triunfo.html"><img src="/images/eterniteshadowedlogo.svg" style="height: 60px;"></img>  </a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Santa Fe</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Dental</a></li>
                  <li class="rightmost"><a href="">More</a></li>
              </ul>

          </nav>
      </header>

      <div class="hide"></div>
      <section id="calendar">
        
         <ul id="days">
           <li>Sunday</li>
           <li>Monday</li>
           <li>Tuesday</li>
           <li>Wednesday</li>
           <li>Thursday</li>
           <li>Friday</li>
           <li>Saturday</li>
         </ul> 

        <div id="hours">
            <ul>
              <li>9AM</li>
              <li>10AM</li>
              <li>11AM</li>
              <li>12PM</li>
              <li>1PM</li>
              <li>2PM</li>
              <li>3PM</li>
              <li>4PM</li>
              <li>5PM</li>
              <li>6PM</li>
              <li>7PM</li>

            </ul>
          </div>


          </section>
  </body>
</html>
```